# How to access Metallb loadbalancer service from internet?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, metallb

We have a K8S cluster that was installed with Kubespray, since it's on prem we configured MetalLB to assign external IPs to our lb services.

The services get the external IPs from the provided IP pool range.
By running the curl command on those services (from inside the cluster's VPC) we get the right response and the lb feature works.

Now we assigned a lb service to nginx-ingress controller which is deployed as a DaemonSet and everything works on the LAN.

How can we make that service accessible from outside the cluster?
Which node's public IP should be exposed to the end user and how to expose it?

Answer (score -1):

If you deployed this [nginx-ingress controller](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/) as a daemonset, ports 80 and 443 of the Ingress Controller container are mapped to the same ports of the node where the container is running. To access the Ingress Controller, use those ports(80 & 443) and an IP address of any node of the cluster where the Ingress Controller is running.

If your nodes have public IPs, accessing any of them, following your ingress object rules, should allow you to access applications from outside the cluster.